# Limit of Continuous Function of Convergent Sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, limits

Let $f:\mathbb{R}$ → $\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function and ${a_n}$ be a convergent sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ with $\lim_{n\to\infty} {a_n} = a $ and $f(a) \neq 0$.

Show there there is a positive integer $N$ such that $|f(a_n)| \geq \frac{|f(a)|}{3}$ for all $n \geq N$.

Comment: What have you tried? What are your thoughts on the question ?

Comment: The key for that exercise is that there is a $\delta>0$ such that $|f(x)|>0$ for all $x\in (a-\delta,a+\delta)$ by continuity of $f$. Now you can use the fact, that $(a_n)$ is convergent.

Comment: @Fakemistake : $f$ may be a negative funciton.

Comment: @MOMO What does it change to his argument ?

Comment: @nicomezi : Because it was $f(x)>0$ before they edited it to $|f(x)|>0$. So it literally changed his argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sequence $(a_n)$ tends to $a$ and $f$ is continuous : therefore, the sequence $(f(a_n))$ tends to $f(a)$.

Let $\varepsilon = 2\frac{|f(a)|}{3}$. You have $\varepsilon > 0$ because $f(a) \neq 0$. By definition of the convergence, there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n \geq N$, you have
$$|f(a_n) - f(a) | \leq \varepsilon$$

In particular, for all $n \geq N$, 
$$|f(a_n)| \geq |f(a)| - \varepsilon = |f(a)| - 2\frac{|f(a)|}{3} = \frac{|f(a)|}{3}$$

This is what you wanted to show.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:**

As $f(a_n)$ tends to $f(a)$, $f(a_n)$ eventually remains in a small neighborhood of $f(a)$, such as $\left(\dfrac{f(a)}3,\dfrac{5f(a)}3\right)$.

Note that the absolute value is immaterial, WLOG $f>0$.